# What do you do when you have to name a class that starts with a number?

Tags: c#, naming-conventions

I have a set of classes named like with the following pattern :

```
{CompanyName}Analyzer // example : AbcAnalyzer
```

Now I have to create a class for a company named 123 and following the pattern the name should be

```
123Analyzer
```

but this is illegal in C#. How do you solve this? Are there any recommendations for classes that are supposed to start with a number?

Comment: Yes, I thought about that but it doesn't feel right. Do you have any links supporting this convention?

Comment: if you end up in this situation, you should probably reevaluate your naming convention.  how about Company{name}Analyzer?

Comment: @KevinNacios I like this one. It makes sense and it's not ugly. Thanks for the suggestion. If you add it as an answer I will accept it if nothing better comes up.

Comment: Yeah @HansPassant, very constructive, you know all about my project and my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Company{name}Analyzer`

this works around the number issue.  I would still evaluate if there is a way to make it more generic so you dont have a new class for every company, but understand that isn't always an option.

Comment: Just to clarify, I don't have a class for each company, there are about 3-4 such classes and the companies are websites. How would you name a class that implements the google search api? Don't tell me that you wouldn't use something that starts with Google...

Comment: @Curious you use GoogleAPI as a name but since its not automated you can use any name you want

Answer (score 1):

you can do

```
    public class _123Analyzer
    {
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do it like this:

```
Analyzer{ComnanyName}
{
}
```